How can I access Incus container with SSH connect from VSCode?
Context
I have a host that runs on Fedora 38 (yes, I know, I'll upgade soon).
I have a few LXC containers that I can access with VSCode (VSCodium, actually, if that makes any difference). I use the extension "Open Remote - SSH" for that.
When setting up a new LXC, I run the command:
lxc file push ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [container_id]/root/.ssh/authorized_keys

I then edit ~/.ssh/config to add:
Host [container_id]
    HostName [container_ip]
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubKeyAuthentication yes

After that, I can access the container from the host, through VSCode.
My problem
I recently set up Incus, to slowly replace my old LXC containers with this fork project. Unfortunately, when I follow the same procedure, it doesn't work!
The error I am getting upon connection is:
[Info  - 09:01:43.509] Resolving ssh remote authority 'ssh-remote+dummy-incus' (attemp #1)
[Trace  - 09:01:43.531] Identity keys:
/home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXX
[Info  - 09:01:43.584] Trying no-auth authentication
[Info  - 09:01:43.628] Trying publickey authentication: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXX
[Info  - 09:01:43.679] Trying password authentication
[Error  - 09:01:49.99] Error resolving authority
Error: All configured authentication methods failed

While doing that, VSCode prompts for a password for root@container-ip.
I think I remember configuring something with my now quite old LXC setup, but I can't remember what. Do I need to configure something specific for Incus to work? SELinux, maybe? (The usual suspect)
NOTE: if it makes any difference, I installed LXC/LXD with Snap, but Incus with DNF.

Can anyone with 300 rep. create the tag incus and add it to the question, please?

The problem is with incus file push ….
By default, Incus pushes files with a non-root user. If you look closely at the file permissions with incus exec [container_id] -- ls -l /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, you will see
-rw-r--r--. 1 ubuntu ubuntu 567 Sep  2 08:15 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

The two ubuntu mean that they belong to a default non-root users. You can simply fix that by running:
incus exec [container_id] -- chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

I do not know if the owner of the files pushed with that command can be configured (and where).
For the next time, you can define the user and group while pushing:
incus file push --uid 0 --gid 0 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [container_id]/root/.ssh/authorized_keys

The --uid 0 and --gid 0 define that you push as user 0 (root) and group 0 (root) respectively.
